# Changing error with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to change 'Enter text here' to 'something else'.

[image: Full code]

I cannot access to server files, so I need to do it with a javascript-code. The following code is not working:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
  $(function() { 
    $(".ws-po-box:contains('enter text here')").text('something else');
  });
</script>
```

EDIT: Typo only when asking, not in code.

Comment: Is this JS code getting executed after the document loading? Try placing them after the body tag, I guess.

Comment: maybe it is a case sensitive issue? Have you tried  `Enter text here`?

Comment: I doubt `:contains` works for `case-insensitive` content..

Comment: I fixed the typo, still nothing.

Comment: The `language` attribute is [deprecated since HTML4](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a typo in your syntax.  Try:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
      $(function() { 
         $(".ws-po-box:contains('Enter text here')").text('something else');
      });
</script>
```

Comment: I fixed the typo, still nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jQuery.filter` for selecting case-insensitive content as `:contains` selector deals with case-sensitive `textContent`

```js
$(function() {
  $(".ws-po-box").filter(function() {
    return this.textContent.toLowerCase() === 'enter text here';
  }).text('something else');
});
```

Comment: I fixed the typo, still nothing.

Comment: I never mentioned about `typo`